# Calling common function from different threads synchronously

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I have a requirement where I need to send out an email based on the triggers that gets activated dynamically. I have briefed my current architecture of code in below image.

In the below image I have class **Sample.cpp** which has **Common** function where I send an email. This **Common** function is being called in a single thread from function **triggerFun** in **EmailClass**. **EmailClass** gets called dynamically by multiple classes like shown in below image.

My requirement is I want to synchronize the usage of **common** function across multiple threads. Means I want to only one thread to call **common** function at a time. After competition of usage **common** function in first thread, then want to allow second thread to allow to execute **common** function, etc....

Could you please let me know if there is any way I can synchronize the threads in usage of function **common**.

[EmailImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmXot.jpg)

Comment: are you looking for `std::mutex` ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, in my case more than 10 threads try to access "Common" function. So when I use mutex, does all remaining threads wait for Common function to be unlocked from previous thread function and then remaining threads gets executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::mutex`.

```
void common() {
  static std::mutex m;
  std::lock_guard lck(m);
  
  // do something

}
```

Comment: in my case more than 10 threads try to access "Common" function. So when I use mutex, does all remaining threads wait for Common function to be unlocked from previous thread function and then remaining threads gets executed?

Comment: @masthan Yes that's what mutexes are for. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) for more info.